# Creating Angular Web Component in existing project

Tags: angular, web-component

I have an existing Angular application. Now the idea is, that some of its components should be exported as web-components and used in other projects.

I have my components in Angular as usual, and I'm making a web component out of them like this:

```js
// constructor of app.module
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const webComponent = createCustomElement(UIButtonComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('ui-button', webComponent);
  }
```

Then, I build the component with:

```
ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

But somehow the building the project results in having a built version of the application. There's no change when I create th custom elements on the one hand, and not creating them on the other hand.

I would have expected something differences in the `dist` folder, like a seperate folder for the element, like:
`/dist/ui-button/<built files>`

So I have two questions:

- Is my concept actually working: To have an existing application, and make some of its components to web components (which will be separately built)? Or can I only create web-components in a seperate project?
- Am I doing something wrong in setting up/building the web components?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The question is really - how would you then like to use the webcomponent? In an external app? Although elements is okay-ish - there is indeed no process available as far as I know to actually also package your component into a single chunk. There are script examples out there on how to do this (google for it) - usually using cat and gzip to create a single js file for your WC. Here is more advanced info on how to do this for multiple web components: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-compile-your-angular-components-library-into-web-components-47ff0ac73bd7

Comment: Yes, I have seen the solutions with `cat` and `concat` to merge all those files. So, does that mean, that for web components I need to create an own project for all the web components? Or is it even one project per web component? That would be quite some overhead in my opinion...

Comment: There is some definite overhead there. Don't forget that Angular Elements is basically just a web component wrapper around a full angular application.  Although my linked article contains some tricks to make it a bit more efficient.

Comment: Frameworks built houses, Web Components are the bricks. What you now want is that your built house splits _itself_ into bricks again. You can't, because you did not built individual bricks in the first place. You built an Application. It can be done; but you have to start with Lego bricks (as separate projects), not a Framework (be it React, Angular, Vue or Svelte) that cements all bricks together.